# Post do metão em inglês na página inicial

Tags: bug, status-intencional, tradução, boletim-da-comunidade

Tem uma publicação que não é do meta do SOpt na página inicial

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Talvez seja intencional, vou perguntar para o Gabe.

Comment: Não estou vendo acontecer mais, será que alguém já corrigiu?

Comment: Também não vi ele novamente. Ficou por cerca de meia hora

Comment: O post em inglês que aparece hoje no boletim esclarece que isso é intencional: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234453/redesigned-community-bulletin.

Comment: Como este é o único site da rede que não é em inglês, a inconsistência de idioma só existe pra gente. Mesmo assim, eu acho bom termos links para posts importantes do MSE ali.

Comment: ^^^^ Ah é, senão a gente vira aquela comunidade caipira que não se relaciona com o mundo exterior.

Comment: Se bem que nós somos o mundo exterior deles, né...